# UUID migration Mysql stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, uuid

I am new to stored Procedure, My requirement is to write a single stored procedure to have UUID column Populated for 1 table as listed below.

Table:  Student

1. Add a new column UUID to all three table
2. Generate UUID and convert to binary format
3. populate each record of all 3 table with binary format generated in step 2.

can some one help me on this. It should be Mysql procedure

DDL for Student as reference

```
CREATE TABLE Student(
    student_id INT, 
    name VARCHAR(100), 
    age INT)
    UUID varBinary(16); -- UUID is new column
```

Comment: Show real DDLs for all 3 tables.

Comment: can someone please help

Answer (score 1):

> Table: Student
>
> 1.Add a new column UUID to all three table
>
> 2.Generate UUID and convert to binary format

```
ALTER TABLE Student ADD COLUMN UUID Binary(16);
UPDATE Student SET UUID = UUID_TO_BIN(UUID());
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c013774608287e574f9ccd39a1d5d88)